# High Memory Use on RDS Instance for Wordpress Environment

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, wordpress, rds, elastic-beanstalk

I am currently hosting a Wordpress site built using Elastic Beanstalk. I've been trying to cut costs and one of the more costly parts of my current environment is the RDS instance. The RDS instance is a T2.Medium running on average 0.33% CPU, 10% Storage but almost 60% Memory. Ideally I would like to drop the instance down to a T2.Small but that would halve the available memory... so, my question is, why is my memory usage so high and is there anything I can do to reduce the memory usage?

I appreciate everyone's time in helping me with this. I'll do my best to provide any information that might help clarify any details I've left out :)

Nate

Comment: I should add, the memory usage remains at approx. 60% (40% available) while my RDS dashboard claims there are no active connections to the instance...

Comment: Which Database Engine is your RDS instance using? MySQL?

Comment: Yup, MySQL... :)

Answer (score 0):

Operating Systems and Databases use memory to cache information that would otherwise need to be retrieved from disk. This provides a substantial performance increase, as retrieving information from system RAM is many orders of magnitude faster than retrieving it from disk, even if that disk is a fast SSD.

So, *can* you move to a smaller instance? Yes, very likely. However, doing so will lead to reduced performance due to the fact that less of your working set will be able to be cached in RAM. Whether or not the performance hit is acceptable is a decision that you will need to make on your own.

Using the RDS snapshot/clone features, you can easily bring up another RDS instance to test this.

Comment: Full agree with this. It's even worth trying a t2.micro, they have 1GB of RAM should should be MORE than enough for most moderate sized Wordpress blogs.You could also install MySQL on an EC2 instance, but that will be less reliable and more work than RDS, but cheaper. I doubt it'll be supported by Elastic Beanstalk though.